# AngualrJS scope variables are updating but not UI

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS + cordova for a mobile application. I am able to display a list view, In that I am  trying to update a list item when I click on that item, the values are changing but the UI is not updating.
Here is my code.

```
  <md-list post class="" role="list" >
      <md-item class="card" ng-repeat="post in posts">
          <div class="card-header">
              <div class="pro-pic">
                  <img src="{{post.UserImage}}" />
              </div>
              <h2>{{ post.UserName }}
                  <span>{{ post.CreatedDate | date:'medium' }} via --</span>
              </h2>
              <div class="post-info">{{ post.Description }}</div>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-img" ng-hide="post.IdeaImagePost == 0">
                  <img src="{{ post.IdeaImagePost }}" />
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card-footer">
              <div id="likeID" ng-click="onLike(post)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up {{post.LikeUserStatus ? 'active' : ''}}"></i><label>&nbsp;Like</label><span class="badge badge-xs badge-pink">{{ post.LikeUsersCount }}</span></div>
              <div><i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>&nbsp;Comment<span class="badge badge-xs badge-pink">{{ post.CommentsCount }}</span></div>
          </div>
      </md-item>
    </md-list>
```

View More

Here is JS code

```
$scope.onLike = function(post) {
    console.log("LikeUserStatus: "  + post.LikeUserStatus);
  post.LikeUserStatus = !post.LikeUserStatus;
  post.LikeUsersCount = post.LikeUserStatus ? parseInt(post.LikeUsersCount)+1 : parseInt(post.LikeUsersCount)-1;

    console.log("LikeUserStatus: "  + post.LikeUserStatus);
};
```

Comment: where are you seeing values changed?

Comment: I am able to print console logs

Answer (score 0):

```js
 console.log("LikeUserStatus: "  + post.LikeUserStatus);
 ` $timeout(function(){
    post.LikeUserStatus = !post.LikeUserStatus;
    post.LikeUsersCount = post.LikeUserStatus ? parseInt(post.LikeUsersCount)+1 :parseInt(post.LikeUsersCount)-1        
})`;
```

$timeout runs the digest cycle after execution

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this is not working, I'm facing this issue in the mobile. As I open the mobile the code is working as expected for the list items which are displayed on the screen mobile, As I scroll down for the next list items the code is not working.

Comment: okays, then i dont have a solution, will have to look deeper into it